# Merge [browser-caching] into [browser-cache]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

Please merge [browser-caching](/questions/tagged/browser-caching) into [browser-cache](/questions/tagged/browser-cache) and create a synonym as they seem to cover same subject.

86 questions are using [browser-cache](/questions/tagged/browser-cache), and 23 questions are using [browser-caching](/questions/tagged/browser-caching). Even if those 23 can be manually retagged, it doesn't guarantee that there will be new entries with that tag, and I don't see anybody using them for different things.

Comment: Create synonym will be better.

Comment: If `browser-caching` is the more popular tag, shouldn't they be merged the other way around?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk, isn't that what I ask for? :) Martijin, wrote it wrong way, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Tags with the same meaning, is meaningless!

**e.g.,**

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244145/cache-frame-content) was tagged like:

```
caching frame browser-cache browser-caching
```

And this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958597/how-to-ensure-that-vs2008-debugger-refreshes-mvc-2-web-page) was tagged like:

```
visual-studio-2008 asp.net-mvc-2 caching browser-cache browser-caching
```

*Users have applied three cache related tags to identify a cache problem on a single question.*

---

**Currently:**

> [image]

They really should be merged, thus removing the [browser-caching](/questions/tagged/browser-caching).

Comment: If there is a tag that is synonym, the tag should not burninate.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, thanks for the heads up!